# styling div content in Angular thru the use of local template variables and material components

Tags: css, angular

In this implementation below, I got an md-sidenav component with a local template variable #sidenavsearchArea.

```
    <md-sidenav #sidenavSearchArea align="" mode="push" opened="false">
       sidenav content here..
    </md-sidenav>
```

I'd like to style the area where it says "sidenav content here.."

How do you refer to this section from the styles.css?

```
md-sidenav #sidenavSearchArea {
   /* does not seem to be the right way */
}
```

My only solution was to break the DRY principle and introduce a new ID ( id="sidenavSearchArea" into the component ) and do it the old school way, like this:

```
    <md-sidenav id="sidenavSearchArea" #sidenavSearchArea align="" mode="push" opened="false">
        sidenav content here..
    </md-sidenav>
```

style.css

```
#sidenavSearchArea {
    /* this approach works but not DRY */
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same thing without the addition of id=""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template variables are only for Angulars internal use. They are never added to the DOM and therefore not available for CSS styling.

You need to additionally add something that is available to CSS selectors, like a class:

```
<md-sidenav class="sidenavSearchArea" #sidenavSearchArea align="" mode="push" opened="false">
   sidenav content here..
</md-sidenav>
```

```
md-sidenav.sidenavSearchArea {
   /* does not seem to be the right way */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.mat-drawer{
  background-color:red;
}
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YdKdXxpEeASiE4vOhQMf?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Vega, thanks a lot for the plunker. This is a general solution but very useful for me for other times. Thank you anyway. According to Gunter, it is not possible to utilize the local template variables in a DRY fashion. :(